# Rails request.referer

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

Im trying to friendly forward the user back to the requesting page that sent the edit request. However request.referer just gives me the same page I am on (the edit page) and thus the redirect does not work.

```
def edit
   session[:return_to_contact] = request.referer
   @user = current_user
end

def update
  if @contact.update_attributes(contact_params)
    flash[:success] = "Contact Updated!"
    redirect_to session.delete(:return_to_contact)
  else
    render 'edit'
  end
end
```

I think the issue is that edit is being called twice. Once from the previous page and then again by the current edit page but I cant figure out why...

Comment: Are you sure that line is even being run and not just the render 'edit' line?

Comment: The contact record is being updated. Im also looking at what request.referer returns at the edit method and its not the url I'm expecting. So the update_attributes is not failing.

Comment: I think the issue is that edit is being called twice. Once from the previous page and then again by the current edit page but I cant figure out why...

Comment: maybe then `session[:return_to_contact] ||= request.referer`

Answer (score 1):

The problem was how I implemented the link_to method.

```
<%= link_to "Edit", edit_user_contact_path(@user, contact),
                                 title: contact.lastname,
                                 class: "btn btn-small btn-secondary" %>
```

I need to include 'method: :get' inside link_to like this:

```
<%= link_to "Edit", edit_user_contact_path(@user, contact), 
                                 method: :get,
                                 title: contact.lastname,
                                 class: "btn btn-small btn-secondary" %>
```

Not sure though why the first link_to construction would still work but cause 'edit' to be called twice.